# Django Get ImageField Path

Tags: python, django, django-views

**models**

```
image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/shows",blank=True,null=True)
```

I am having image_url which I need to parse it using JSON object to my android application. I only need the URL of the image(absolute/relative).

I have tried

```
image_url=myObj.file.url
image_url=myObj.image_url
```

Comment: Check if `myObj.image_url.url` works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct working solution as provided by @alecxe is

```
image_url =myObj.image_url.url
```