# Getting ImageField file path post_delete

Tags: python, django

I'm making a little piece of software with Django and JS that will handle image uploads. So far, so good. I'm getting nice little images via AJAX from dropzone.js. They are saved on the file system and have an ImageField in my Photo model to keep track of what is stored and where.

I even stabbed dropzone.js to nicely ask my dev server to delete the database entries and the files themselves. I find that the latter part is lacking a bit. So I started writing a function that catches a post_delete signal from my Photo model and has the task of handling the deletion from the file system. The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to get my hands on the file path that's stored in database.

If I've understood correctly, the following should work:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Photo(models.Model):
imageFile = models.ImageField(upload_to=generateImageFileNameAndPath)

@receiver(post_delete, sender=Photo)
def cleanupImageFiles(sender, **kwargs):
    print("Cleanup called")
    p = kwargs['instance']
    path = p.imageFile.name
    print(path)
```

But when I try to output `path` to the console, there's nothing.

Sorry about the upperCasing instead of using under_scores as seems to be Python convention. I personally find the underscore convention a bit annoying and am having a wrestling match inside my head over whether to follow the convention or just go my own way. For now, I've done the latter.

edit: I can't seem to make it work with `p.imageFile.url` either as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740651/django-get-imagefield-path?rq=1).

editedit: I also tried with pre_delete signal thinking that maybe post_delete the data has already been blown to smithereens, which would be dumb, but who knows :)

edit3: calling imageFile.path, doesn't cut it either. It just produces

```
[27/Nov/2016 22:29:08] "POST /correcturl/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 200 
Cleanup called
[27/Nov/2016 22:29:15] "DELETE /correcturl/upload/  HTTP/1.1" 500 37
```

on the console window. The HTTP error 500 just comes from the view not being able to handle the delete call because of this code not working properly. That's what I use as status message to the frontend at this point.
It might be worth noting, that if I do

```
print(p)
```

the output on the console is

```
Photo object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew I had to have done some stupid and finally had time to get back to debugging.

In my view I'd done

```
deletable = Photo(id=id)
```

instead of

```
deletable = Photo.objects.get(id=id)
```

thus ending up with a new photo object with just the id field filled in. Because Photo.save() was never called this didn't end up in my DB and no errors were thrown. Because of this, the bug flew stealthily under my radar.

Thus, when finally calling

```
deletable.delete()
```

it only removed the uncomplete instance I had just created. Although, it also deleted the proper entry from the DB. This is what threw me off and made me mostly look elsewhere for the problem thinking I had the correct database object in my hands.

Where this behavior came from remains unclear to me. Does delete() actually check the database for the id (which it in this case would've found) instead of just handling the instance in question? I guess taking a look at django.db.models.Model.delete() could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the path of the image, try:

```
path = p.imageField.path
```

P.S.: Yes, you should follow the convention. Otherwise it will be hard for others to read your code if you share it with somebody, or contribute to an open source project, or hire programmers in your company, etc.

Comment: @xtrom0rt Hmm... interesting. Let me get back to you after trying it out.

Comment: Yeah, it' strange. If I do instance.pk, it gives me the right primary key for the row, so we should have a decent handle on the object instance. Yet it behaves strangely.